# How to specify positions in a matrix by an array?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

If I have an array of sets of points such as

```
pts = {{2,4},{1,3},{5,7}}
```

Is there any super short command to use those pairs to output their respective elements in a matrix in one felt swoop without loops?

Also, is there a way to output elements of an array corresponding to just the first or just the second element in all pairs?
so given an array

```
array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

output only

```
{2,1,5}
```

corresponding to the first element in each pair in pts

Comment: Take a look at `Part`, `Extract`, `Span` and friends. `array[[pts[[All, 1]]]]`.

Comment: @Kuba, perfect, thank you!

Comment: @Kuba ups! Haven't read your comment in time. Sorry

Comment: @belisarius I don't think you should be, why? :)

Comment: @Kuba I used Extract in my answer and you suggested that a pair of minuts before in your comment. Nothing to worry about, I guess!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[42];
pts = {{2, 4}, {1, 3}, {5, 7}};
a = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {7, 7}]
Extract[a, pts]
(* {2, 9, 10} *)

Grid[a, Background -> {None, None, Thread[pts -> Red]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: great! thank you!

Comment: Haha, very fancy XD